# MS Access 365 doesn't show Name hyperlinks to newly added Sharepoint library entries

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint Library that is imported into MS Access 365 as a linked Sharepoint List. My objective is to use the automatically provided hyperlink in the Name field to quickly view documents in the library. It works great for original entries. However, not all entries in the sharepoint library has a value in the Name Field in MS Access; it seems that after the creation of the Access-database, new entries in the library doesn't get a value in the Name Field in MS Access. In the Sharepoint library online using a web browser, the Name column looks just normal.

I have added files to the Library using the Sharepoint Library Upload button, and also drag and drop into the browser. I only add files using Sharepoint Online, not by adding records in MS Access. In MS Access I can see the newly added files or folders, and all fields except the name field seems to be correctly updated.

Looking at the library in MS Access; the Name field is a hyperlink. It seems not to be a calculated field, so the information in the hyperlink should be found in a Sharepoint Library Online Column. Is the Name Field in MS Access actually the same thing as the Name Column in the Sharepoint Library online?

I have tried to delete the linked Table and add the library again, but with the same result. However, If I create a new database and link the same Sharepoint Library, all entries get their Name fields correct, even the ones that were missing in the other database. New entries in the Library after creating the new database gets the same issue; no Name Field value.

The Compact and repair tools doesn't make any difference.

Can I (should I?) run an update query in MS Access to update the Name field? Would this ruin the Sharepoint Library online?

Any help would be appriciated, as I have searched for answers but found none applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in answers.microsoft.com by Microsoft Agent, 15 may 2021.

Bug fix will be applied in next update of MSAccess365. Meanwhile, Workaround is as follows;

In MSAccess, goto Linked Table Manager, select the library and click relink. This will update all new entries.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-365-doesnt-update-name-field-of-a-linked/ba461c17-0670-49d0-a565-4ee5bdd96d37